# EmberJS: Access item views from collection view

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How can I access the item views from a collection? Basically I have a table (my collection view) which has rows (as the itemViewClasses). I want to add a particular property to the row I click on and remove that property from all other rows of the table. I want a way to refer to my item views from the collection view so that I can keep a track of which row has that property and add or remove the property (more like set and reset the property) (like a radio button)

Comment: add a click handler to the itemViewClass-view maybe, so you get reference to the item you just clicked. Adding a fiddle might grab more attention :).

Comment: the clickhandler will let me add or remove property from that particular row, hence I will lose reference to the previous row from which I should remove the property now. Can I treat the itemViewClass like an array or a hash and index the views somehow? I will just add a fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/inertia/aTJhv/1/

Comment: Did you consider using Ember.CollectionView and manipulate its content property ? http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.CollectionView

Comment: Manipulating the content property will help me change whats rendered. How can I change a specific property of the child view I click on and remove that property from all other child views of that collection? The only solution I see is to somehow get a reference from the parent(collection View) to each child view which I am unable to find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a boolean property "isSelected"(Initially set to false) to each of the element during the initialization.

Whenever you click on any of the element set the "isSelected" property of all the elements to "false".

Then set the "isSelected" property of current "content"(in the itemViewClass) to true.

Now, in the handlebars use {{bindAttr class="isSelected:active"}} to apply corresponding CSS to your table row. Hope this helps !